# Including all the library statically instead of parts of the library upon linking/compilation

Tags: c, gcc, static-libraries

If I am to statically link a certain library to my application, As far as I know, the linker could optimize in a way to put only the parts that had been used from the library while generating the final executable. Is there a way to turn this off upon compilation, maybe using a compiler flag or any other particular method, if I want to generate an executable containing all the parts of the library instead of the portions that I had actually used?

Comment: Why?  Why is code bloat desirable?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler it's for some research work, not for production or other purposes :)

Comment: Which doesn't answer my question — why is the code bloat desirable.  It may not be harmful because it is for research only, but why do you consider it desirable?  However, there's an element of "rhetorical question" to my question — and those don't necessarily get answers.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler -- fairly sure the actual answer to this is something else, since nothing said so far makes sense.  If you want to look at the library you can just look at the library file.  :shrug:

Comment: @Hogan: an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) indeed.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler &hogan We are doing work related to possibility of fingerprinting libraries for embedded system. We want to make sure that the executable file contains all the functions related to library because we are going to fingerprint these disassembly code to potential executables that are not having their original source code. Having executable with all the functions would make our work easier of matching the binaries. We needed to find whether there's a way of linking all the library functions without  actually using them. Please don't judge others. If you can't answer please let go.

Comment: @Hogan Above comment applies to you too! People are doing different types of work, their necessity are different, don't just think from one angle and judge others depending on what you think

Comment: I "let go" with my previous comment to you — you are taking unnecessary umbrage.

Comment: @hEShaN -- you are funny -- there is nothing in my comment that was judging except to say you were not telling us what you are doing.  Now that you have told us, and it makes sense, my comment no longer applies.  Don't assume I was judging.  If you are being secretive and hiding things -- don't be shocked when people point that out.  Both Jonathan and myself understand the topic well enough to know we were not hearing the full story.

Answer (score 6):

There is a GNU linker option `--whole-archive` which does exactly that:

> For each archive mentioned on the command line after the
>              `--whole-archive` option, include every object file in the archive
>              in the link, rather than searching the archive for the required
>              object files.  This is normally used to turn an archive file into
>              a shared library, forcing every object to be included in the
>              resulting shared library.

See [`man ld`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ld.1.html) for more details.

When you link with `gcc` or `clang` pass this option to linker as `-Wl,--whole-archive`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to work with linkers other than the GNU linker, you may find it best to create one relinkable object file from the component object files in the library, and then build that (large) object file into a replacement library.  It becomes an all-or-nothing proposition: if you need any of the symbols in the library, you get everything.

```sh
oldlib=/some/where/libwhatnot.a
newlib=libwhatnot1.a
bigobj=libwhatnot.o
tmpdir=libwhatnot.relink

mkdir "$tmpdir"
cd "$tmpdir"
ar x "$oldlib"
ld -r -o "../$bigobj" *
rm -f *
cd ..
rmdir "$tmpdir"
ar r "$newlib" "$bigobj"
rm -f "$bigobj"
```

You might need to review how to preserve debug information (likely a `-g` option to `ld`).

The script should deal with problems such as the directory already existing and failing to `cd` into it — the `rm -f *` could do grievous mischief if that is executed in a directory other than the one that was just created.  But the basic idea — extract, build a single object file, archive that — means that the library is all or nothing, as desired.

You also have to arrange to replace the original static archive with your replacement, either by changing the name of the library used in linking, or by placing your replacement in a directory ahead of the original in the linker command line, or by renaming the original, moving the replacement into its place, and continuing as before.  I recommend keeping the original until you're confident you won't need it again.

The `-r` option has existed on linkers since (at least) 7th Edition Unix in the late 70s; it is usually available and usually unused.